# What exactly is done to a UIView on interface rotation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

could someone explain what iOS does on rotation of the interface. I´ve got a layout problem with one View that is gone after rotating the iPhone. Seems that the View got set a new frame, bounds or whatever, don´t know. Anyhow after the interface was rotated once the layoutproblem is gone forever. So something must be set to the view at the time the interface rotates.

I´m loading the View from a NIB file and show it with a navigationcontroller:

```
BirthdayReminderWidgetConfigViewController *vc = [self.storyboard
    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BirthdayConfigController"];
self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:true];
```

Maybe there is some setting I have to do in order to show up the view correct without rotating the interface.

I´ve got a layout problem with a view that is loaded from a nib file as follows:

The project contains a MainStoryboard. Within that, I load a view from a nib file.

```
NSArray *xib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View" owner:self options:nil];
self.configViewController = [xib objectAtIndex:0];
```

The storyboard has a navigation controller and the loaded view is shown like this:

```
    if (currentWidgetConfigViewController != nil)
    {
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:currentWidgetConfigViewController animated:true];
    }
```

So in my opinion nothing wrong? (First question)
But now the problem.

What I designed is that:

[image]

What iOS does is the following

[image]

The controls are not arranged well.

And besides that with a button on the new view I open up a PeoplePicker with that code:

```
[self presentViewController:self.picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

After closing the People picker with `[self.picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];` I get this result:

[image]

So what is going wrong here?

Comment: You will have to change the frame of view everytime the view rotates itself.As the landscape view has lesser height than portrait mode, so if any of your view is below 320 in landscape or beyond 320 in portrait ,it is bound to be hidden.Hope it is clear enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

Override `-setFrame:` and `-setBounds:` in your view to see what happens:

```
- (void) setFrame: (CGRect) newFrame
{
    NSLog(@"New frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(newFrame));
    [super setFrame:newFrame];
}
```

Also, the `transform` usually changes during a rotation. [Orientation Zoo](https://github.com/zoul/Orientation-Zoo) might help, it’s a sample Xcode project showing what happens in various rotation use cases. Didn’t touch it for a long time, though, so I don’t know if it still works.